# login and completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlsession

I'm developing an app with a login page. When the app is launched, the login screen is shown, and you cannot access the app until you are connected. To connect to the app, you enter your username and your password. When you press the "connect" button, json data containing the username and password is sent to a web service, which check if the credentials exists. If they exists, the server send a json file containing "exists":"true"

The problem is that the code checking this Json file is in completionHandler of my NSURLSession, and the method return "NO" before the Json data is checked, so I can not connect to my app. As it's hard to explain, here is my code:

GSBconnexion.m:

```
#import "GSBconnexion.h"

@implementation GSBconnexion





-(bool)logConnexionWithUserName:(NSString *)username
                     password:(NSString *)password{


    __block BOOL allowConnexion;
    NSDictionary *connexion = @{
                                 @"username": username,
                                 @"password": password,
                                 @"target": @"app"
                                 };


    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonLogData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:connexion                                                 options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];


if (! jsonLogData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
}



NSData *logData = jsonLogData;
NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:logData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *logLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[testString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.5.133:1337/login"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:logLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-lenght"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:logData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSDictionary *serverResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:
                                    NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    int canIConnect = [serverResponse[@"exist"] intValue];

    NSLog(@"%d",canIConnect);




if (canIConnect  == 1) {
        NSLog(@"OKKK");
        allowConnexion = YES;
        NSString *sessionID = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:serverResponse[@"_id"]];
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:sessionID forKey:@"SessionID"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

            NSLog(@"ID Session:%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"sessionID"]);
    }

    else {

        allowConnexion=NO;
    }

}] resume];

NSLog(@"JSON envoyé: \n\n%@",testString);

return allowConnexion;
}



@end
```

GSBLoginController:

```
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

    connectButton.hidden = YES;
    loading.hidden = NO;

    UIViewController* homePage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homePage"];

    GSBconnexion *login = [[GSBconnexion alloc]init];

    NSString *username = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",usernameTextField.text];
    NSString *password = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",pwdTextField.text];

    BOOL authorized = [login logConnexionWithUserName:username password:password];
    if (authorized) {
        [self presentViewController:homePage animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else {
        connectButton.hidden = NO;
        loading.hidden=YES;
        usernameTextField.text=@"";
        pwdTextField.text=@"";
        errorLabel.text = @"Connexion impossible, merci de réessayer.\nSi le  problème persiste, veuillez contacter un administrateur.";
    }

    NSLog(authorized ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

I hope you understood me, thanks for your help!

Simon

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're expecting a return value from a method that is executing asynchronously. So basically `return allowConnexion` is happening immediately even though the dataTask is still ongoing in the background. Thus, you're relying on an incorrect value. Basically what you want to do is copy what is happening in the dataTask w/ a completion handler.

So you could say something like `typedef void (^CompletionBlock) (BOOL isFinished);`

Then change your login method to include the completion block as its last argument and return nothing:

```
-(void)logConnexionWithUserName:(NSString *)username
                     password:(NSString *)password
                     withCompletion:(CompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

Then inside of the dataTask's completionHandler call the `completionBlock` passing in the value of `allowConnexion`.

Finally once you've done all that in your login view controller you'll implement this new method, and inside of the completion block you can update your view accordingly. Its going to look something like this:

```
- (void)thingWithCompletion:(CompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completionBlock(YES);
    });
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self thingWithCompletion:^(BOOL isFinished) {
        //update UI
    }];
}
```

Be advised that since you're on a background thread and going to update UI on completion you're going to want to dispatch to the main queue as well. That is why the call to `completionBlock(YES);` is wrapped in the `dispatch_async` call.